# Query in SQL Server (machines that are now in specific project)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table including 3 fields which are `Machine Name`, `Project Name`, `Date Time`
where `Date Time` indicates the exact time when machine was assigned to a project.

Now I want to find machines which are now in a specific project (in fact it may be that one machine in different times be allocated to different projects).

I want lasted specific project be latest project that machine assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can use this:

```
select t1.ProjectName,
  t2.Datetime,
  t2.MachineName
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select max(datetime) DateTime, MachineName
  from yourtable
  group by MachineName
) t2
  on t1.machinename = t2.machinename
  and t1.datetime = t2.datetime
```

Or even:

```
select projectname, datetime, machinename
from 
(
  select projectname,
    datetime,
    machinename,
    row_number() over(partition by machinename order by datetime desc) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I want machines that now be in specific project , may machines "a", 2 days ago in project "1" and now be in project "2" , when I wand machines in project "1" , Should not machine "a" be in result .

Comment: @user1788354 will project 1 now have a different machine associated with it?